# Significance of explanatory variables in Bayesian models

Tags: regression, machine-learning, bayesian, bayes

I was wondering if there is a general way to handle parameters of which posterior distributions include zero. 
Should one remove these parameters and refit the model?

E.g.
You fit a regression model y = N(a + B_1*x_1 + B_2*x2,sigma).

Now, B_2's posterior includes zero, maybe p(B_2 = 0) = 10%. Should one consider B_2 insignificant, throw it out of the model and refit?

Comment: With a continuous prior, we always have $P(\beta_2=0)=0$... Do you mean that $0$ belongs to a certain confidence region on $\beta_2$?

Comment: Yes.  e.g  the posterior on B_2 could be N(0.5,0.5)

Comment: So what i'm asking is, is there any general way of handling insignificant parameters for bayesian models. For example if 0 is inside a 95% credible interval for a certain parameter, should one keep it in the model?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it does not use the idea of "significance."  Indeed, it is not clear at all that zero being inside the interval is meaningful in Bayesian methods as an idea.  For Frequentist models the null is held to be true and so if $\beta=0$ then that implies that if the null is not falsified then the null can be treated as provisionally true.

Instead, in Bayesian methods, model selection is the rough equivalent to variable significance testing.  Consider, for example, three variables $\{a,b,c\}$ being used to estimate $y$.  Assuming some simple form, the possible combinations of  variables that matter are $\{(a),(b),(c),(a,b),(a,c),(b,c),(a,b,c)\}.$

For simplicity, let's assume the $P(Model=(a,b)\to{y})\gg{P}(Model\ne(a,b)\to{y})$ so $P(Model=(a,b)\to{y})\gg{P}(Model=(a,b,c)\to{y})$.  The difference is that $c$ is missing from the best model, so this is similar to saying $c$ is not significant.  Notice that there is no requirement that $c$ is near zero.

Answer (score 1):

Even in frequentist model building using a criterion of $p\leq 0.05$ for a whether a parameter should be in a model is not in general a useful approach. It may to some extent be reasonable for judging whether a variable is associated with the outcome (when there are multiple parameters there is clearly a multiplicity problem when doing so). However, it is not appropriate to remove such a variable from the model (either based on whether some value is in the posterior credible interval, some model probability or the like), simply re-fit it and then make statements based on the remaining model (i.e. do model selection and then do inference as if no model selection had occurred) - whether these statements are about the association of the remaining variables with the outcome, about prediction or any other thing. When you are in a Bayesian framework this does not become any more appropriate.

Many of the same strategies as in frequentist inference can be considered in a Bayesian setting when there is model uncertainty. E.g. Bayesian model averaging with priors given to each model, various approximations to a full Bayesian model averaging (e.g. model weights based on $\exp(-\text{BIC}/2)$, using shrinkage priors like the horseshoe etc.), methods that can potentially set coefficients exactly to zero (mostly maximum-a-posteriori methods), cross-validation and so on.